# What options are there to process text which was extracted from pdf to remove text wrapping / justified effect

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, text-mining

I have been able to extract text from multiple pdf files but the original files had double line spacing within 1 column of text which was wrapped or justified so my extracted text also has alot of `CR` `LF` within. My issue is when the text wraps sentences also contain `CR` `LF`

toy example

```
This sentence continues

on this line. Next ....
```

I don't want to loose all the spacing structure like paragraphs so is there a way to unwrap (un-justify) text using python without removing all spacing in the document or intelligently join the lines back?

Eventually I want to spell check the text with Spacy after additional text processing to handle non english text but the justified/wrapped text may be causing misspellings and difficultly detecting all the non english text.

Comment: Can you post desired output? Do you want to remove `\r\n' form text?

Comment: A bit more than that, I want to rejoin sentences that due to formatting of the original pdfs span across multiple lines. I'm not interested in removing all `\r\n' just the ones that artificially break sentences

Comment: But how do you know which `'\r\n'` artificially breaks sentence and which not? The original text could break sentence everywhere.

Comment: thats my problem

Comment: One possibility is that maybe the PDF contains "unicode newlines" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode which have different code in addition to `CR` `LF` - maybe this can help you to recognize artificial breaks from original ones.

Comment: take https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf as an example. I assume each sentence wasn't manually edited to look this way but instead is some combination of justified text and text wrapping. How would I go back from this text layout to just the source text so it easier for carry out text processing?

Comment: What library did you use to obtain the text?

Comment: I used Tika parser to extract the content from each pdf file but the text wasn't corrected following whatever ocr was done on the pdf originally